# Yii2 hide a web part in URL using a .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, yii2

I have created a `.htaccess` file in my root folder that contains the following code:

```
-RewriteEngine On
Add a comment to this line
-RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/web
-RewriteRule ^/?([^/]+)$ /web/$1 [L]
```

but it doesn't work as expected. I also have a `.htaccess` file in web folder that contains the following code:

```
RewriteEngine on
# If a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# Otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```

What am I doing wrong, here?

Answer (score 2):

Put in `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteRule . /web/index.php
```

Or

```
RewriteRule . /basic/web/index.php
```

EDIT.
I find better solution. Put in `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain.com$ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !web/
RewriteRule (.*) /web/$1 [L]
```

Change `domain.com` to your domain.

Comment: where should i create a .htaccess file?

Comment: Yes. Take your first .htaccess in your question-post.

Comment: where should i put this .htaccess folder

Comment: Put `.htaccess` under `web` folder.

Answer (score 1):

should change the AppAsset public $css  path

Comment: Please elaborate your answer.

Comment: you should move the contents of web folder outside (which i wont recommend) or change the path of css and js files    <pre>    <code>    public $css = [ 'web/css/site.css' ]    </code>    </pre>

Answer (score 0):

Add **.htaccess** *outside of the web folder*

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

Options +FollowSymLinks
IndexIgnore */*
RewriteEngine on

# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```

Add following in **config/web.php**

```
'urlManager' => array(
        'class' => 'yii\web\UrlManager',
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'showScriptName' => false,
        'rules' => array(
            '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/view',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
        ),
    ),
```

move **index.php** *from inside of the web folder to outside* and change these 3 lines

```
require(__DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php');
require(__DIR__ . '/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/Yii.php');

$config = require(__DIR__ . '/config/web.php');
```

This is working for me in both development and production.

Comment: i want to hide a web folder in url .I have made my url pretty using the above code at present my url is: mysite.com/web/<controller>/<action>  i want it to be mysite.com/<controller>/<action>

Comment: what about the resources available in web folder ?Why yii2 by default has a web folder

Comment: You can still use all the resources available in web folder.